# How to measure time needed for creating a dialog box?

Tags: c++, performance

how to measure time needed for creating a dialog box?
Do I do it in a ctor at the beginning of it and then at the end? Would that be correct?

Comment: What platform? What framework?

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer and why according to you either platform or framework would make the difference to the method used while measuring the time? Would that method depend on either of them?

Comment: Because "creating a dialog box" is ambiguous. Does this mean just the C++ class representing the dialog? Or does it mean the construction and display of the actual display object on screen? The latter will depend entirely on the GUI framework being used.

Comment: #GazTheDestroyer but method for measuring will be still same.

Comment: No it won't because different frameworks have different methods for displaying a dialog. For instance MFC would require constructing the C++ class, then calling ShowDialog(), and then hooking into OnInitDialog() to determine when display constuction has finished.

Comment: "The end" is really fuzzily defined. Even `OnInitDialog` doesn't mean it's visible to the user.

Comment: #GazTheDestroyer and what has a method of displaying widget to do with method of measuring the time needed to do so? Method for measuring will be same and at least similat principles will apply.

Comment: #MSalters end in this particular scenario usually means the place where ctor of a class finished its work, doesn't it? Oh, here we go, rain of bullshit from so called professionals will prove me that this isn't true. Ok, I'm waiting.

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you want to time only code inside the constructor, of the whole chain including allocations and parent class initializations.

If you want all, including possible inheritance chains, then you need to do it when creating your class:

```
clock_t start = clock();
CMyDialog *myDlg = new CMyDialog;
clock_t end = clock();
```